# Openlayers 3: Why forEachFeatureAtPixel only return one feature

Tags: openlayers-3

I create a text box where I can put the coordinates X,Y then I move the pin to the location and find which roads are there.

The pin move, but `forEachFeatureAtPixel` only return one feature instead of four. Also the feature I got doesn't have `NOMBRE` property

I'm using Openlayer 3 and my WMS server map.
As you can see in MapInfo (picture right side) I got all 4 features.
 Horizontal 2x "Calle 6" and Vertical 2x "Calle 1 Norte", and have `NOMBRE` property. 
I'm using the same x, y from mapinfo where all 4 feature instersect.

**new info: My layer is ol.layer.Tile instead of ol.layer.Vector, maybe that is the problem (checking)**

```
wmsLyr09 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: wmsSource
});
```

[image]

```
// move the pin to new position
geometry.translate(deltaX, deltaY);

var coordinate = geometry.getCoordinates();
var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
console.log('pixel: ' + pixel);

var allFeaturesAtPixel = [];
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function (feature) {
    allFeaturesAtPixel.push(feature);
});

// feature[len]:1
console.log("feature[len]:" + allFeaturesAtPixel.length);

//feature[Name]: undefined
feature= allFeaturesAtPixel[0];
console.log("feature[Name]: " + feature.get('NOMBRE'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your map you probably have two layers, the WMS tile layer and the vector layer for the pin. So, OpenLayers doesn't know about the road features. If you are calling `forEachFeatureAtPixel` you are getting the only feature OpenLayers knows about: the pin.

What you want to do is make a WFS GetFeature request to get the features at the current pin position. Take a look at this example: http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/getfeatureinfo-tile.html

Comment: WFS GetFeature, doesnt bring geometry or allow select, does it? Im updating my tool to bring a few roads link in the area and create another temporal vector layer, so user can select road links.

Comment: You can also get the geometry. Make a GetFeature request and parse the returned GML with `ol.format.GML`: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.GML.html?unstable=true